# Ionic MenuController get evaluating 'this.menuInnerEl.offsetWidth' on ios

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I use the MenuController on the Ionic project
Sometimes I got the error **error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.menuInnerEl.offsetWidth')**
this error make my iOS app freezes (working no problem on Android)
anyone know about this error please help?

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.4.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1100.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.2.1
   @angular/cli                  : 10.2.1
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.0.0
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve the issue? I have the exact some thing in my app from time to time. Stil investigating the issue

Comment: Not yet, If I can fix will update

Comment: I have a workaround for my situation but it might not work for yours. I put all my ion-menu's in the app component's html instead of the page that calls them (which was lazy loaded). Hope this helps you.

Comment: I kind of did the same, eagerly loaded the landing module instead of lazily loading it.